# Sublime text gives error on creating a build system for c++ 14

Tags: c++, windows, sublimetext3, mingw

I created a new build system in my Sublime Text 3 for C++ 14 and pasted the below code and saved it as c++ 14.

```
{
 "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
 "variants":
 [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "cmd":["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++14 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
   }
 ]
}
```

But whenever I select this build (saved `C++ 14`) to run my c++ program then my Sublime Text gives the following error :

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['bash', '-c', "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall 'C:\\Users\\ragha\\Desktop\\All_Folders\\sublime_cpp\\_code.cpp' -o 'C:\\Users\\ragha\\Desktop\\All_Folders\\sublime_cpp/_code' && 'C:\\Users\\ragha\\Desktop\\All_Folders\\sublime_cpp/_code'"]]
[dir: C:\Users\ragha\Desktop\All_Folders\sublime_cpp]
[path: C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Python38\python.exe;C:\Python38;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\ragha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;]
[Finished]
```

NOTE - I HAVE ALREADY INSTALLED MinGW C++ INSTALLER. I have added C:/MinGw/bin to the path in both `Global Variables as well as System Variables`. My C++ program runs well when I run it using `C++ single file` build. I don't have any WSL in my system.

How to fix the problem.

Please Help!

Comment: If you're just using `MinGW` and you're not using `WSL`, then you probably don't have `bash`, and you also don't need it. The difference between the built in build and yours is largely that. Just copy the contents of `C++ Single File.sublime-build` and modify the arguments, no `bash` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a new build system to try:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "bash -c \"g++ -std=c++14 -Wall '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "variants": [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "'${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }]
}
```

The `"shell_cmd"` takes all of its arguments as one string, so I combined it all together with escaped double quotes as needed, and made some tweaks so that it runs, at least for me.

I also changed your `Run` section to just run the already-compiled binary. In your original one you were compiling again before running. You'll notice that I used the `"cmd"` function here, where the arguments are an array of comma-separated strings.

Please note that this build system still runs the binary inside Sublime's console, so you can't do some things, like request input from the user. However, if you would like to run your program in a separate command prompt in order to accept user input, for example, use this build system below:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe && start cmd /k ${file_path}/${file_base_name}",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "variants": [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
        "working_dir": "${file_path}",
        "shell": true,

    }]
}
```

#### EDIT

If you just want to compile and run your program *inside* Sublime, this should work:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe && ${file_path}/${file_base_name}",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "variants": [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["$file_base_name"],
        "working_dir": "${file_path}",
        "shell": true,

    }]
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one. An error came :
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: bash -c "g++ -std=c++14 -Wall 'C:\Users\ragha\Desktop\All_Folders\sublime_cpp\_code.cpp' -o 'C:\Users\ragha\Desktop\All_Folders\sublime_cpp/_code.exe' && 'C:\Users\ragha\Desktop\All_Folders\sublime_cpp/_code'"]
[dir: C:\Users\ragha\Desktop\All_Folders\sublime_cpp]

Comment: Using the second one, my cmd gets open. I don't want to use cmd as I am taking input from input file input.txt and I am showing the output to output.txt. 
My code.cpp, input.txt and output.txt all three are in same directory.

Comment: @ MattDMo The EDIT one worked. Thanks. Now my program is running fine.